# Merging Branch Locally and on GitHub

Tags: git, github

This is a basic newbie question about `Git` and `GitHub`. I just want to make sure I'm doing it right.

I have a local `Git` as well as a `GitHub` repo for my `ReactNative` project. I have `Master` and `Develop` branches and in order to test out `native-base` UI library, I created a new branch named `NativeBase`. I now want to `merge` the `NativeBase` branch back into `Develop` both locally and on GitHub.

Are the following the correct steps to do this?

1. I make sure I'm on `Develop` branch by issuing `git checkout develop` in my terminal
2. Then issuing `git merge nativebase` will merge the `NativeBase` into `Develop`
3. I think the next step is to get the updated `Develop` onto `GitHub` by issuing `git push -u origin develop`

One thing I'm not clear about is what happens to the `NativeBase` branch on `GitHub`. I think Step 2 here will remove the `NativeBase` branch locally because it's now merged into `Develop`. Is that correct?

Also, is this how I need to update/merge `GitHub` repos after a `merge` locally?

Comment: With an addition of you may want to `git pull` after 1 and before 2... this work, but actually depends on your workflow. Namely, it'd work if you push directly into your remote branches, but if you use GitHub's pull request to merge content into branches in GitHub repo, it'd look differently: you push `NativeBase` as new remote branch, make PR to merge into `Develop`.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you're saying steps 1 and 2 are correct for merging locally but after that you suggest I push my changes from local `NativeBase` branch to the `NativeBase` branch on `GitHub` and merge them on `GitHub`. Am I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes and no. It was more of hint/question. That order does depend on how you've setup (or want) to have your workflow. Whether you (people) are expected to push directly in `Develop` or make Pull Requests to have their work merged on GitHub.

Comment: I see and I do appreciate your point because it does depend on one's preferred workflow. I think, and I could be wrong, but it's probably a better idea to `merge` on `GitHub`. I don't think I'd like a developer single-handedly merging and killing a feature branch just because he/she thinks it's good to go. So, then steps 1 and 2 are good and replace step 3 with perform merge on `GitHub`. Obviously, the very first thing to do is to push `NativeBase` to `GitHub` so that we have an updated branch there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think Step 2 here will remove the NativeBase branch locally because
>   it's now merged into Develop

This is not true although all the info and history of the branch are now in the `Develop` branch. You have to delete the NativeBase branch.

```
git branch -d NativeBase
```

`-d` is safe and recommended because it will make sure that all the commits from `NativeBase` are moved to the `Develop` branch before deletion.

> what happens to the NativeBase branch on GitHub

Nothing unless you do something explicitly. You have to delete it on the remote host.

```
git push origin --delete NativeBase
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the first point. I want to make sure I'm 100% clear about  what `git push origin --delete NativeBase` will do. It seems it will first push the updates to `NativeBase` and then delete it. If the idea is to delete this branch, why `push` the code? Is it also safe to assume I'm also issuing `git push origin develop` after my local merge?

Comment: please check this for [git push --delete](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)